# Differentiation of Bessel function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions

How can I represent the following differentiation in terms of $J_n$?
The equation is: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[xJ_n'(x)]$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$\frac{n^2-x^2}{x} J_n(x)$$

You can get it using two properties of Bessel function:

$$J'_n(x) = \frac12(J_{n-1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x))$$

$$J_n(x) = \frac{x}{2n}(J_{n-1}(x)+J_{n+1}(x))$$